# How to win in this game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, game-theory, dice

You select 10 numbers from the set $\{2,3,\dots,12\}$. 
You then continually roll 2 fair dice and sum them up, until your selection of 10  numbers come up.

For example if your selection was 7,7,7,7,8,8,8,6,6,6 (4 7's, 3 8's and 3 6's), and you roll the dice repeatedly and get 7,7,6,5,8,7,7,9,8,3,5,10,12,6,6,3,2,5,7,9,8, you may stop now because 4 7's have come up, 3 8's and 3 6's.

What is the best choice of 10 numbers so as to minimise the number of rolls ?

Comment: What have you tried?  For $2$ numbers instead of $10$, I suppose that $\{6,8\}$ is optimal, no?  What's the answer for $3$?

Comment: @EthanBolker  I believe so, yes.  It helps that you can get either a $6$ or an $8$ to start.

Comment: how can you show that for 2 numbers instead of 10 {6,8} is optimal.

Wouldnt it make more sense {7,8} or {7,6} is better than {6,8} ?

Comment: @lulu You're right. I deleted the comment suggesting $(7,7)$ you are answering.

Comment: You might be right!  I was asking you what you had learned.  I am only sure that $\{7,7\}$ is sub-optimal.

Comment: I've learnt a lot - too much to write on this comment :P 

Kidding, this is just an interesting qn my friend asked me.

Comment: It's a good problem (+1).  I'll write it up for $2$ choices.  The method should at least give a recurrence method for proceeding, but there is almost certainly a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Cool question! I would pick: $4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10$. Just guessing here though!

Comment: My friends guess is 7776688459 - if he is right i owe him a car :(

Comment: @Namch96 Fortunately there are those little toy cars .... :)

Comment: My intuition would suggest to take values in proportion to their probabilities (round the values and if they don't add up correctly, favour the more probable). So here we would take $10*\frac{1}{6} \approx 2$ sevens, $10*\frac{5}{36} \approx 1$ eights and sixes, $10*\frac{4}{6} \approx 1$ nines and fives and so on.

Comment: By the way, I have asked a general sort of question like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645985/optimal-way-to-choose-a-prediction-for-a-random-variable

Comment: @ploosu2  So that would suggest $3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,11$ ... hmm, I like it. Darn for that first pick of mine! OK, someone figure this out please!

Comment: @Bram28 Simulation seems to indicate that $4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10$ is way better than $3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,11 $. The simulated expectations I got were around $28$ and $35$. Then for example for $5,5, 6,6, 7,7,7, 8,8, 9$ I got $\approx 29$. I think the "proportion argument" isn't any good when the values it gives aren't integers :D. Or, we don't know how to round them.

Comment: @ploosu2 Oh, interesting!  So my first guess is still in the running after all ... :)

Comment: @ploosu2 Oh, can you please try $4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9$?  That was the guess of the OP's friend ... apparently a car is at stake!

Comment: @Bram28 With my simulation $A_1 := \mathbb{E}[4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9 ] \approx 28.2$ or $28.3$. The previous $A_2 := \mathbb{E}[4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10]$ around $28$ is really close (in the same range). I keep getting $A_1 < A_2$ but I wouldn't trust the small decimals too much : ).

Answer (score 4):

Using a brute-force exhaustive search, and a recursion for each case, I get the following answer:

There are two equivalent optimal strategies, namely
$$4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9$$
$$5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,10$$
yielding, for the expected number of rounds,
$$
e=\frac{a}{b} \approx 28.26676327
$$
where
$$
\begin{align*}
a&=71526610479792733682076713232552201067\\[4pt]
b&=2530413892848114144358747803518976000\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
$$
**Remarks:**

Intuitively, the multiplicities of the selected numbers should be in proportion to their probability of occurring in a single round.

Thus, for example, for the simpler game where you roll a single die, and get to guess $6$ numbers, the optimal selection is $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

If in each round you roll two dice, and get to guess $36$ numbers, I suspect the optimal selection is
$$2,
3,3,
4,4,4,
5,5,5,5,
6,6,6,6,6,
7,7,7,7,7,7,
8,8,8,8,8,
9,9,9,9,
10,10,10,
11,11,
12
$$
For the game in question, where in each round you roll two dice, and get to guess $10$ numbers, then, since the multiplicities for the selected values must be nonnegative integers, it's not possible for the multiplicities to be in proportion to the associated probabilities. Yet, it's intuitive that they should be *approximately* in those proportions.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, but not a full answer).  I'll work it out for $n=2$, $n$ being the number of values you select.

Let $E[a,b]$ be the expected number of throws it take assuming you chose $a,b$.  Similarly, let $E[a]$ be the expected number of throws it takes just to see $a$.  Of course $E[a]=\frac 1{P(a)}$.

For $a=b$ clearly choosing $7$ is best.  In that case one sees at once that $$\boxed{E[7,7]=\frac 2{P(7)}=12}$$

Now assume that $a\neq b$.

Considering the possible outcomes of the first toss (i.e. "$a$", "$b$", or neither) it is easy to see that $$E[a,b]=P(a)\times \left(E[b]+1\right)+P(b)\times \left(E[a]+1\right)+(1-P(a)-P(b))\times \left(E[a,b]+1\right)$$

This implies that $$\boxed {E[a,b]=\frac {P(a)P(b)+P(a)+P(b)}{P(a)P(b)(P(a)+P(b))}}$$

It is easy to compute that $$E[7,8]=E[7,6]=9.92727\cdots<12$$  and that $$E[6,8]=10.8$$ so as the OP expected, choosing $\{7,6\}$ or $\{7,8\}$ is optimal. (remark:  it is not difficult to rule out the other possibilities, by direct computation if nothing else.)

Note I:  this method generalizes to more choices but the cases start to multiply badly.  My guess for $n=3$ would be $\{6,7,8\}$ but I have not verified this and it could easily be incorrect.

Note II:  this method certainly lends itself to automation.  If you have computed all the expectations for $n$ choices then you can get them for $n+1$ by a recursion as was done above.  This is hardly a pencil and paper method, however.  there are $\binom {19}9=92378$ possible selections when $n=9$ and $\binom {20}{10}=184756$ when $n=10$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not see your "It is easy to see that..." How do you obtain this formula? Is it something easily known?

Comment: @TrivialCase  Consider the first toss.  You either get an $a$, or a $b$, or neither.  If you get an $a$ then you are waiting for a $b$...so you have $E[b]$ to wait on average (and have already taken one toss).  Similarly if you get a $b$.  If you toss neither then you are right back where you started but you have taken a toss.

Comment: I see it now, thank you!

Comment: @TrivialCase  No problem.  It should be a fairly easy matter to handle $n=3$ from here.  I mean, surely the answer is $\{6,7,8\}$ or $\{7,7,6\,\text{or}\,8\}$.  I'm trying to see how to get at larger $n$ directly but this recursive method is the best I have so far.

Comment: Simulation I ran gives $\mathbb{E}[6,7,8] \approx 12.5$ and $\mathbb{E}[6,7,7] \approx 14.1$.

Comment: I think the difficulty comes in assessing when a multiple choice is made instead of selecting a previously unselected number. This has to happen by the time you have to choose twelve numbers anyway. My intuition suggests that a binomial distribution of choices centred around $7$ might end up being something like the right answer.

Comment: @ploosu2  I get $E[6,7,8]=12.50\overline {45}$ via the recursion (but didn't check the algebra too carefully).  I'll take your simulation as sufficient cause to trust the algebra!

Comment: @MarkBennet  Absolutely correct.  That tends to block any algebraic trick I can think of to short circuit the recursions.

Comment: I built a little JS program to test this out in the console. I used the idea that $$E[a_0 , \ldots , a_n] = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(a_k) \left( 1+E[\overline{a_k}] \right) \right) + \left( 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(a_k) \right) \left( 1 + E[a_0, \ldots , a_n] \right)$$ to get $$E[a_0 , \ldots , a_n] = \frac{1}{\sum P(a_k)} \left( 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(a_k) + \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(a_k) \left( 1+E[\overline{a_k}] \right) \right).$$ . It gives correct answers for arrays of size 2 and 3, with $E[6, 7, 8] = 12.504545454545452$ but it takes 30s for each array of size 10, so not going to do all arrays...

Comment: @TrivialCase  Well, the difficulty is that the recursion has to handle repeated selections correctly.  If you were required to choose different values, the algebra would be simpler.  In any case, the sum in the recursion needs to be taken over the distinct values that are selected, not over each of the values.

Comment: I should add that by $[\overline{a_k}]$ I mean the array $[a_0 , \ldots , a_{k-1}, a_{k+1}  , \ldots , a_n$

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, I could add in code to check that condition easily enough, like if two values are the same then return $\frac{2}{P(a)}$, but still going to take forever.

Comment: Ok so best for n=1 is 7, then the best for n=2 is the multiset {6,7} or {8,7}. We then have (we think) best for n=3 is the multiset {6,7,8}. I wonder if for n=4 the best multiset will contain {6,7,8} as a subset - in which case we only need 1 more number, which will either be a repeat, and if it is a repeat the repeat should be 7, or a new number 5 or 9.